# UnderscoreJS template escapes JS operators

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm having an issue where JavaScript operators in my UnderscoreJS Template are escaped and therefore unusable.

Escaped characters that I found are &&, >, <.

I've looked for another similar issue but couldn't find any.

Where is the problem?

My template is:

```
<div class="list-feedbacks-container" style="display: block;">
    {{ _.each(collection, function(model) {

        if (model.id > 0)
        {
            // This can't be execute, the line above raised an error
        }
    }}
</div>
```

The error raised in Firebug is:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after condition
    if (model.id &gt; 0)                        {                            //
```

[image: Firebug error]

Here's my view:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.list-container',

    events: {
        ...
    },

    /**
     *  Initiliaze the view variables and listeners of the view
     */
    initialize: function(){

        // Change delimiter from <% %> to {{ }}
            _.templateSettings = {
            interpolate: /\{\{\=(.+?)\}\}/g,
            evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
        };

        this.collection = new myCollection();

        this.render();
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store your templates inside `<div>`s or anything else that is HTML. Anything that is considered to be HTML by the browser will be corrected to be valid HTML and templates are rarely going to be valid HTML. The result is a confusing mess.

Instead, store your templates inside a container whose contents will be left alone. Usually you use a `<script>` with an appropriate content type:

```
<script id="whatever" type="text/x-underscore-template">
    <div class="list-feedbacks-container" style="display: block;">
        {{ _.each(collection, function(model) {
            ...
        }}
    </div>
</script>
```

Then you can

```
var t = _.template($('#whatever').html());
```

to get your template functions without interference.

Comment: Thanks it work! I had to switch <script> and <div> tags to make it work though. And thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Your template should be inside a script as `mu is too short` mentioned. Additionally, your evaluate regular expression is incorrect, because `.` doesn't match newlines. You can try `(?:.|\n)` instead. Finally, you should close your function body with a bracket, and your function call list with a parentheses.

Working example:

HTML:

```
<script id="a" type="mytype">
    <div class="list-feedbacks-container" style="display: block;">
    {{ _.each(collection, function(model) {

        if (model.id > 0)
        {
            print(JSON.stringify(model));
        }
   })}}
   </div>
</script>
```

JavaScript+Underscore.js:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{\=(.+?)\}\}/g,
  evaluate: /\{\{((?:.|\n)+?)\}\}/g,
  //evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g, //<-your code
};

var a = document.getElementById('a');
var templateString = a.innerHTML;

var compiled = _.template(templateString);
var data = compiled({collection: [{id:1},{id:0}]});
console.log(data);
```

You will notice that this console logs the div with the filtered "model" `{id:1}` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

Javascript:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    evaluate:    /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    escape:      /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g
};

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'list-container',
    template: _.template($('#my-template').html()),
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template(this));
      return this;
    },
});


var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
collection.add([
    {id: 10, email: 'foobar10@demo.com'},
    {id: 11, email: 'foobar11@demo.com'}
]);

var myView = new view({collection: collection});
$('#container').html(myView.render().el);
```

Html:

```
<script type="text/template" id="my-template">
    {{ _.each(collection.models, function (model) { }}
         {{ if (model.get('id') === 10) { }}
            <span class="blue">{{= model.get('id')  }}, email: {{- model.get('email')  }}</span>
         {{ } else { }}
            <span class="green">{{= model.get('id')  }}, email: {{- model.get('email')  }}</span>
         {{ } }}
    {{ }) }} 
</script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

You can check a small demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/levieraf/9h85q302/

Let me know if this work for you :)

Good luck man!